# How do I solve 502 error's given from azure hosted bot?

Tags: bots, azure-bot-service

Hello I am currently experiencing a bot connection error for my azure hosted bot. It gives 502's when I send messages and does not send messages back to me what so ever, not even to initiate conversation. When I submit a message for conversation I get a 502 error that reads:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadArgument",
    "message": "Missing token or secret"
  }
}
```

If anyone has some information on this error that would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The reason behind this is because of AAD integration configuration. All the azure bot services are managed by AAD (Azure active directory) and we need to check the active directory configuration with the following steps:

1. Sing into **azure portal**
2. Goto **All services**
3. Select **Azure Active Directory**
4. Select the **Users**
5. Check whether the User Type is guest or not. If it is **guest**, make it **member**

[image]

6. After configuring the user, to make the users to utilize the service of the bot, create **resource group**
7. Register the app under App Registration and enable the option for users to **can register applications** and make it **YES**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To update the application service
If you have an existing App Service (web app) resource for your bot and the bot is a user-assigned managed identity app, you may need to update the bot's app service:

Go to the App Service blade of the bot web application.
Under Settings, select Identity.
On the Identity sheet, select the User Assigned tab and Add (+).
On the Add user-assigned managed identity blade:
Select your subscription.

Under User-assigned managed identities, select the bot's managed identity. If the managed identity was automatically generated, it will get the same name as the bot.

Select Add to use this identity for the bot.